# Необычный input: автоматически переставить курсор на следующее поле

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток,есть вот такое поле http://floomby.ru/s1/GaTY3V , как сделать так, чтобы когда вводишь в первое поле, номер телефона, при достижении определенного количества цифр автоматом перекидывало на второе поле а затем на третье, т.е. не надо ставить курсор на новое поле самому. Вот тут https://loanup.com/application/#step-1 если заполнить все поля формы и перейти на 2 шаг есть такое поле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот примитивный примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/93KBy/). Только я поставил для всех полей ограничения в 5 символов, а вам надо будет высчитывать и устанавливать для каждого поля самому. А можно [сделать массивчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/93KBy/1/) и вытягивать кол-во символов из него.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery Group Inputs](http://lusever.github.io/groupinputs/) — хороший плагин, гибкие настройки

Comment: Ну либо самому, примерно так http://jsfiddle.net/Tu6sm/

Comment: @RubaXa, Для задачки в "три строки" использовать плагины? Куда мир катится? ))

Comment: Я бы посмотрел эти три строчки, которые будут поддерживать: backspace, перемещение стрелками и copy/past.

Comment: событие input поддерживает copy/past если мне не изменяет память. keyup поддерживает backspace

Comment: Поддержка тут не причем, я говорю про логику. На past нужно перехватывать буфер и распределять его по инпутам, при перемещении стрелками, нужно... посмотрите исходники плагина, вот они ваши "три строчки".

Comment: @RubaXa, ну ну.. Во-первых, про три строчки говорил я и, как можно понять, говорил образно. Во-вторых, есть определенные требования по функционалу и, в зависимости от них, пишется тот или иной код. Плагины же, в подавляющем большинстве случаев, содержат функционал, который юзером не используется. Ладно, если таких плагинов подключено пара штук и весят не много, но если таких с десяток, то это может значительно утяжелить страницу.

Comment: Ребята всем спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно повесить обработчик события `keyup` на каждое поле, которые будет считать длину значения и в случае достижения максимума переходить на следующее.